# Best persistent data storage system for an alternative to global variables?

Tags: node.js, database, global-variables

I am building a Node.js application which uses a few global variables to track data such as online users and statuses, information about other servers, and ongoing events, but having this information be lost in the event of server restart/crash is not ideal.

As these things are frequently read & modified, I figure it would not be a good idea to put that extra strain on my existing MySQL database. I have looked into Redis but unfortunately my application is hosted on a Windows server so I would have to use an old unsupported version of it which isn't ideal.

I'm currently considering setting up a NoSQL database such as MongoDB, but I'm not sure if this is an efficient solution and if it would be too much on my relatively weak server to have an application and 2 different databases running.

What would be the best solution for persistent storage of data that needs to be frequently accessed and updated by an application?

Comment: If it's a reasonable amount of data, you can just write JSON to a single data file.  No database required.  Just overwrite the file with a new block of JSON to save the new state.  This is very fast, efficient and simple.  I've used this before as a quick and easy way to regularly save snapshots of state that you want to be able to reload if your server restarts.  Read the state into memory upon server start, then use it from memory, then regularly save a new snapshot to disk however often your application desires.

Comment: If some data changes a lot and some data doesn't change very much, you can break the data into multiple files so you're writing less data on the more frequent interval.  Obviously, there is a threshold of amount of data or frequency of writes or complexity of data access where a database would be warranted, but you should at least consider the simpler option first and only add a new database when you think you really need it.

Comment: In the future I may implement clustering so I would also need to be frequently reading from where the data is stored. However, that is a great and simple idea so since I am still running it single-threaded then I am definitely going to do that for now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Making my comments into an answer...

If it's a reasonable amount of data, you can just write JSON to a single data file. No database required. Just overwrite the file with a new block of JSON to save the new state. This is very fast, efficient and simple. I've used this before as a quick and easy way to regularly save snapshots of state that you want to be able to reload if your server restarts. Read the state into memory upon server start, then use it from memory, then regularly save a new snapshot to disk however often your application desires.

If some data changes a lot and some data doesn't change very much, you can break the data into multiple files so you're writing less data on the more frequent interval. Obviously, there is a threshold of amount of data or frequency of writes or complexity of data access where a database would be warranted, but you should at least consider the simpler option first and only add a new database when you think you really need it.

If you cluster your servers in the future, that would speak to a multi-user database (one with appropriate concurrency management features) to be your master keeper of state, but you're going to have other design issues to work through if you're trying to share multi-user state (like online status) across all clustered servers as you can no longer keep that in memory for any server unless all state changes are broadcast to all servers so they can update their in-memory copy of the data or unless you make users sticky to a particular server (which complicates load balancing in clustering). That does somewhat call for a redis-like central store that all clustered servers can access.